# A question about length vs electromagnetic interference relation

Tags: electromagnetism

How can we explain the reason for why EM induced noise increases with the cable or wire length in analog voltage transmission?

My way of thinking is that same current is induced on the wire regardless of its length, but because the longer cable has longer resistance it causes more voltage noise. Is that correct? If not how can this be explained illustratively?

**EDIT**:

If the reason is the larger area hence d(A*B)/dt; then why people need to use diff ended inputs since they can zero the area by twisted wires?

[image]

Comment: Law of induction <- things your should really know when dealing with EM radiation.

Comment: Yes Faraday's law says dPhi/dt is proportional to the voltage induced where Phi is the flux. And flux is related to the area. Is that the reason?

Comment: But why people use differential inputs? Im asking because if we make the area between wires zero by twisting them, there will be no noise induced. In that case why not single ended used for long distances? What I see is they use STP with differential inputs instead of STP with single ended. If the area is made zero by twisting whats the difference between SE and diff ended?

Comment: Twisted pair does not eliminate noise between wires, quite the opposite. It's used mostly because it balances noise induced into the pair when the wires are carried close to each other like in ethernet cable.

Comment: @Barleyman I thought by twisting we are blocking the flux to induce voltage on the wires like in my edit picture. Is that wrong?

Comment: Nope. You're making sure both wires get equal noise from neighbouring wires plus you're minimizing the EMI they radiate due to equal and opposide signals in close proximity. I amended my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My way of thinking is that same current is induced on the wire
>   regardless of its length

It's a mistake to say that current is induced - a voltage is induced (as per Faraday's Law) and the longer the wire the more that induced voltage is. If the wire is terminated in a load this then gives rise to the current you mentioned in your question BUT that current is due to induced voltage and load.

Regards the use of twisted pair - magnetically induced interference on one wire is the same magnitude and polarity as the other wire. Electrically induced voltage is also the same so, if you use a differential amplifier it will subtract the common interference leaving just the signal (theoretically). Line impedances also need to balance for this to happen optimally.

Comment: V-by-one does differential signaling with separated wires. In gigabit class signaling you really need serious impedance control.. It really bothered me when I saw it first time but there's nothing in differential signaling that actually requires the pairs to be, well, paired.

Comment: @Barleyman I'm unsure what your comment is about. Maybe you need to add it to your answer?

Comment: Just that differential signaling does not require that the pair is actually paired. V-by-one essentially uses two separate coax wires for each pair.

Comment: My answer never said anything about "differential signalling". In fact I made a point of not opening that can of worms. Please remove your comment.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the answer and input about about Faraday's law. So longer the wires the larger area and more flux and more voltage induced.. I got your point. But where I'm confused is this: If the wires are twisted(no gap for flux no flow through), why would there be noise induced at all? Or diff ended inputs are in this case works for capacitive common mode noise? I mean doesn't twisting take care of inductive coupling 100%?

Comment: @atomant twisting never 100% eradicates everything that might be coupled magnetically.

Comment: @Andyaka I opened another question a bit related to this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374431/does-magnetic-coupling-cause-common-mode-or-differential-noise-in-this-case Would be great to have your comment on it if you have time

Answer (score 0):

Because the long wire/trace acts as an antenna. Ideally your antenna length should be equal to 1.25 of the wavelength of the signal but also half/quarter/one-eight works.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna

That's the simplest antenna type along with monopole but if you get fancy, much smaller antennas can be made but require non-trivial design process.

### EDIT

With regards to the OP edit -
Twisting wires makes sure the noise in the differential pair is common mode, which will be rejected by the differential receiver. This happens e.g. in ethernet wiring since all of the unrelated wires are bunched up in close proximit to each other. By twisting you make sure both wires get exposed to the same amount of EMI field from nearby wires, or least close enough for reasonable frequencies. In a flat cable one wire would get a lot more than the other. Unless you use G-S-S-G configuration which wastes 1/3rd of your ribbon cable.

The second reason for twisting is to create controlled impedance over the cable length which is important for high-speed data transmission. You can absolutely do this with GND + single ended signal but it's not as good as proper shielding i.e. coax.

On a twisted pair the differential signal EMI gets negated by the equal and opposite signals at close proximity. This would work for flat cable too of course. If you twist two single-ended signal wires together, you maximize cross-talk.

Differential signaling does not actually require paired wires, high speed buses can carry the pairs in separate micro-coax wires.

Comment: Antenna will not pick up more signal proportional to its length.

Comment: @atomant Proportional, no. Larger in key lengths, yes. You will run into the 1/2 wavelength figure in EMI a lot. The important thing to remember that this infamous gap length rule of thumb actually means -3dB attenuation which is not all that great.

Comment: If you're talking about crosstalk, that deals with near-field effects that uses magnetic field coupling but the key word here is "near".

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Im talking about EMI