# DC-DC switching converter PCB design

Tags: led, dc-dc-converter, noise, led-driver, switching-regulator

Recently I had a problem with noises in my led driver. I realized that my PCB design was terrible, so I redesigned whole PCB following common rules.

Could you take a look and check if my new design is ok?

Thanks for all answers. 
[image]

Comment: I've seen worse, but why is L2 placed so far away from U1?

Comment: What do you think about my high dI/dt loop? I mean place around SS14, U1.

Comment: Like I said, I’ve seen worse but what about L2?

Comment: What about a schematic and what about these *"common rules"* that you mention?

Comment: for eg.: 
-minimizing high dI/dt loops
-high peak current traces are as short as possible
-input capacitors are close to IC
-every high current traces are on the same side
-botton layer is GND for better shielding ( maybe not that much significant)

Comment: you need to post a schematic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Jasen said: this will probably work fine, and I also agree with the other comments, about keeping it small etc.

Some additional thoughts:

- C6, C7, C8 are probably not necessary
- Like @winny said: move L2 to the right. In order to do that, you could move C2 to the left, especially if you would decide to omit C6,7,8 (or at least 2 of the 3)
- You can probably do with just one C3, C4 or C5
- All the vias on the left, near the connector can go. Your connector is through hole, and that should be enough
- All the vias near C4/C5 can go, except for maybe one or two
- Most of the vias near C1 can go, max. 4 should be enough
- The vias near C3 can go as well
- If you would 'lower' the Vcc trace on the top, you could make room for the GND trace to connect the connector with C1, and not need any vias at all around your capacitors. You're only drawing 488mA, so that shouldn't be a problem
- The vias underneath U1 are probably *also* for heat? If so, check that there is no solder mask on them
- Besides U1, the other part that will become more warm/hot is D2 and maybe the inductor
- I like the position of D2 and the current sense resistors :-)
- What kind of inductor are you using? It's quite common to use something like this:
  [image: Ferrite inductor]
  As long as it's a ferrite inductor, you're probably ok, just checking.

You might want to consider bringing the DIM pin out to the connector as well. Might be fun for future use... ;-) You can PWM the DIM pin, or apply 0.5 - 2.5V on it to make your LED dimmable.

You're really on the right track here, not bad at all! Just some thoughts and possbily some improvements. And of course this is IMHO.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Today at the evening i will post my new layout.

Answer (score 2):

if you build that it'll probably work fine.

But if you want criticism

placement of D2 close to U1 is good, but C5 should also be close to U1 
(find a smaller part that you put to the right of U1)

Your part labels are misplaced, overlapping parts

The ground plane seems kind of useless, consider using a VCC plane instead and a trace for ground - more parts connect to VCC tan connect to GND

it seems to be missing mounting holes. (or there's just a lot of wasted real-estate on the wast and west ends)

It seems to have lots of extra parts.

see for example figure 3 here:
http://crpowtech.com/Attach/image/20180314/20180314072558_86236.pdf#pdfjs.action=download

[image]

I think that's single sided.

Comment: Mounting holes are not nesserary in this pcb.
Extra parts are for good EMI/EMC performacne.
Its easier to not use smd pads, than creating new ones on existing PCB, am I right?

Comment: there's a lot of empty space with ground both sides, you could put mounting holes there, unless there is some other purpose for that

Comment: the large sise of your board is not helping EMI/EMC

Comment: @Jasen They just said they dont need mounting holes! Ground planes give a consistent, low-impedance ground. The additional capacitors will suppress noise.

Comment: @Jasen Can you explain why large size makes noises? (i my particular case)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374388

Comment: @HarryBeadle A loop (around which switched current flows) is an antenna, a bigger loop couples to the universe better than a small loop,